# Word for Excel column numbering system

Tags: nouns, numbers

In Excel, we have a number set for the columns as such:

A
, B
, C, ..., Z, AA, ...

Is there a name for this "numbering" set? Such as hexadecimal for base-16, or binary for base-2? Or just natural numbers for base-10

Comment: Er... alphabetical? Why does that not work?

Comment: Is that really the term...? I can't seem to find anything on it. I mean I don't mind just making up a name I guess, but if one exists...

Comment: I doubt the ancient Greeks or Romans would have had a word for [***base 26***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=numbers+%22base+26%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) counting - I don't think either of them had 26 letters in their alphabet anyway. But some enterprising scholar here might be able to come up with a latter-day coinage.

Comment: *Base 26 **numbering*** or should it be **lettering**?

Comment: It's not base 26 numbering, because that would start 0,1,2... 9,A,B... O,P,1A,1B... Using only letters, it's [alphabetical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alphabetical).

Comment: @Andrew: The thing about "alphabetical" is it doesn't carry any implication that you might use this counting system for ***multiple*** digits. Besides which, if you include upper and lower case, you could be working in base 52. I myself often used to use base ***62*** because you can represent very big numbers in a short string if you include upper and lower case *and* the digits 0-9. Just because hex includes digits as well as a few letters doesn't imply you'd do that with any other system though.

Comment: In happy to accept base-26 numbering or base-26 lettering, although I was hoping for a coinage of sorts; Excel is widely used and I would have suspected that this would be a named system of counting. Alphabetical is hopeful, but it has no implication that's it's a numbering system as it is already used to describe a set of letters used to form natural language, not arithmetic (I.e., no implication of S(Z)=AA)

Comment: A similar system is available in LaTeX; unfortunately I can't find any official description. Generally the docs just mention \Alph and maybe give an example. I have seen "using alphabetical characters" and similar, suggesting the lack of a better term.

Comment: It's not just base-26 counting, it is *zero-free* base-26 counting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently it's called the [bijective base-26 system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system). It is a base-26 [numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system) where the 26 letters of alphabet are used as the symbols for values 1-26 (there is no zero in this system).

AFAICT, the *bijective* qualifier indicates that no leading/trailing zeros are permitted or possible.

If you're looking for the equivalent of binary, decimal, hexadecimal etc. for base-26, it would be [hexavigesimal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hexavigesimal.html).

Comment: [Bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) in this case means every positive integer has exactly one representation. The fact that no leading zeros are allowed is a consequence of this.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! Not quite as pleasing as if hoped but I guess for the criteria I can't expect much more. Thanks!